# Php crud api return empty array on POST

Tags: php, api

I'm using [php crud api](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/) so the GET and DELETE working perfectly but not the POST and PUT ?

POST REQUEST

```
/records/posts/
```

CONTENT

```
{
    "title": "Black"
}
```

return me an empty array :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
[]
```

and PUT return me :

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"code":1002,"message":"Argument count mismatch in '1'"}
```

GET and DELETE are working nicely , any ideas ?

Comment: Well, either the response from the server is intentionally empty (an empty array), since no matching, or there is an issue in the server side application logic. Which we can say nothing about, since you did not share that logic with us.